# Context Menu location

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a context menu to show up manually by pressing the hotkey ctrl+menu. Therefore i use this function:

```
ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

I call this in my main window. But it has some odd effects.

1. If I only press the menu-key, the menu alwasy appears in the middle of the screen
2. If I manually call the menu, it always appears in the top left corner.

my menu is this one:

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Placement="Center">
        <MenuItem IsCheckable="False" Name="item2" Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="{DynamicResource countDownNotificationOn}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

using the xaml placement above dosen't work either. Therefore I set the window to

```
ContextMenuService.Placement="Center"
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
if (element.ContextMenu != null )
{
    element.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = element;
    element.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

If after this, the `ContextMenu` is still not placed correctly, you can set the placement using the `ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset` and `ContextMenu.VerticalOffset` properties. Take a look at the [ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.horizontaloffset.aspx) and [ContextMenu.VerticalOffset Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.verticaloffset.aspx) pages at MSDN for more information.

Comment: Thank's, it works. I thought it'd be sufficient if I put the placement into the xaml part.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please 'tick' this question as the correct answer if it has helped you to solve your problem.